# Can I retrieve which user analyzed project on SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Having many projects on SonarQube server, can I retrieve which user (name or token ID) executed a concrete project analysis? Can I backtrack the analysis process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that's not available. But since analysis reports are submitted via Web Service (`api/analysis_reports`) you should be able to get IP from the access logs.

Comment: Hi, why do not you ask every user to run the sonar scan with their own user by passing  -Dsonar.login=XXXX -Dsonar.password=XXXX. If you are using SQ 5.3 version,  you can get the submitterLogin details from api/ce/task webservice .This webservice details ,you can get at the end of console log.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ticket to cover this use case in SonarQube 5.6 : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7532: CE should log the login of the submitter of a task when processing it